# Initializers may only be declared within a type swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I got problem with writing a function in a class. I create a class with initialiser and I try to create function, but I am getting the error, wit initializer, could you help me?

> Initializers may only be declared within a type.

**My code:**

```
class JsonParams {
let Login_Token = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
init() {
}

func Jsonrequests (userName: String, password: String){

    let param : [String: Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ self.Login_Token, "session", "login", [ "username": self.userName, "password": self.password]]]
    self.param = param

    return
}
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly then you'll see that `init()` is *inside* the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the empty `init()` and clean your code:

```
class JsonParams {
    let loginToken = "00000000000000000000000000000000"

    func jsonRequests(userName: String, password: String) -> [String:Any] {

        let params: [String : Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0",
                 "id": 1,
                 "method": "call",
                 "params": [ self.loginToken, "session", "login", [ "username": userName, "password": password]]
        ]

        return params
    }
}
```

Afaics you do not want to store the params, so you could also use a static version:

```
class JsonParams {
    static let loginToken = "00000000000000000000000000000000"

    static func createParams(userName: String, password: String) -> [String:Any] {

        let param: [String : Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0",
                                 "id": 1,
                                 "method": "call",
                                 "params": [ self.loginToken, "session", "login", [ "username": userName, "password": password]]
        ]

        return param
    }
}
```

which you could later call like this:

```
let params = JsonParams.createParams(userName: "myName", password: "myPass")
```

You should definitely [learn Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) and conform to [code, naming and style conventions](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide).

Comment: Thank you a lot, you wrote me exactly what I need!!

Comment: One more question, after using static version and passing params to alamofire request I get few errors, which I didn't get with first version of params? Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: params), encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

Comment: And now? Am I supposed to guess which errors and what the reason is? Plus fix it? Static and non-static version should be equivalent afaics. I do not know how the result params are supposed to look like and thus took over your code. I could imagine that you have to swap `self.loginToken` and `"session"` or that the params have to actually be dictionaries: `..."params": [ ["session":self.loginToken], ["login":[ "username": userName, "password": password]]]`. But that is only a guess and also off topic in regards to your question.

Comment: I get same result of params from static and non-static version, but I get errors after I insert static params in request sentence :expected expression; Consecutive statments on a line must be sepated by ;, default label can only appear inside a switch statement. I can upload photo, but it would be offtopic

Comment: Yes. Do some effort yourself. Double check the type and format expected by the method you pass the params to. Try things, debug, think, search the net. If you can not make it, ask a new question.

Comment: Still big thank you, you helped me a lot!! Now I am trying to solve.